# Why do we need to set Max and Min thread in .Net?

Tags: threadpool

I am struggling in a thread project. I came across the setMaxThread , SetMinThread, GetMaxThread and GetAvailableThread. I didn't find any good reason to use those methods in the threadpool.

Help me out here,
why do we need it and when do we use it?

Answer (score 1):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx)

> There is **one thread pool per process**. Beginning with the .NET
>   Framework 4, the default size of the thread pool for a process depends
>   on several factors, such as the size of the virtual address space. A
>   process can call the GetMaxThreads method to determine the number of
>   threads. The number of threads in the thread pool can be changed by
>   using the SetMaxThreads method.

If you don't want to use the default value, use setter method to change your process's thread pool.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I understand what you are saying but my real question is why do we need to change the number of threads especially decreasing the size of the threads.

Comment: It is about prioritization. If you want to give less power to a process and timing is not a critical factor, even though there is a work to do, they will be queued and processed later due to minimal number of available threds.